# Big Data Analysis Simulation

Tags: hadoop, cloud, data-analysis

First post ever, so here we go! (Thanks for taking the time to read!)

I am currently studying in college and working on a research project on how different hardware (specifically a ram-disk vs hard rive) can affect the speed of big data analysis. I know how to set up the various hardware and all of that jazz, however, I have no previous experience with big data analysis, and after looking for a few days I have found no answers (even here). I need any software to be able to simulate big data analysis - I have read of Hadoop, but have no idea where to begin on that - and it seems that even with it there is no simulation. *How would I go about getting software along with data to analyze? Specifically, something I could run as a control group and then again with the data stored on a ram-disk in order to see if there is a performance increase.*

I really feel in over my head here and don't know where to start, so any help or tips are welcome. Thank you very much!

To clarify, I am hoping to begin on a very small-scale database, but I also have resources with my school to set up a very large drive to be able to test with.

Comment: This is off topic [help/on-topic]. Try [stats.SE]

Comment: *getting software along with data* - Plenty of open source datasets exist if you just search for them. There's also "Hadoop, the Definitive Guide" book that uses some of those to do analysis. Note: If you want to use memory, you'd more than likely use Apache Spark maybe with Apache Ignite. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There are many DB solutions out there in the market. 
However, the big data DB must be designed to process this particular data. The characteristics of big data are summarized as 3V which means data volume, velocity, and variety. 
Big data is a large amount of data in terabytes(TB) or more. This is the most basic feature of big data, which means that there is a large amount of data that is still being generated through multiple paths. 
Also, large amounts of data must be collected and analyzed in real time in accordance with the user’s needs. The diversity of big data has various forms. That is, it includes all types of data such as a regular, semi-regular and irregular data. In addition to traditional instructed data such as books, magazines, medical records, video and audio, it also includes the data which have location information. 
[Machbase database](http://machbase.com) is one of big data software you can try. This DB website also offers the user manual and the page of getting started, where users can easily follow instructions. Good luck!!